# extending linked list return issue

Tags: java, string, class, accessor

I'm trying to extend the LinkedList class but i'm getting a strange error, whenever i try to add an accessor class that returns a string i get the error

found   : java.lang.String
required: String

I cant work out why this is happening. (I'm pretty new to linked lists and java in general, be nice :) )

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyLinkedList<String> extends LinkedList<String>
{
   private int count;     //for future use

   public void MyLinkedList()
   {
      count = 0;
   }

   public boolean add(String s)
   {
     boolean x =  super.add(s); 
     count++;
     return x;

   }


   public String toString()
   {
      return("test");
   }


}
```

Comment: First, you don't have a constructor. You need to remove the `void`.

Comment: By the way, it´s not a good idea to create a subclass of an existing list implementation for such purpose. Use delegation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your declaration to

```
public class MyLinkedList extends LinkedList<String>
```

By adding `<String>` to your `MyLinkedList` class name you create a new type parameter whose name *shadows* the real class `String`.

Comment: It’s *shadowing*. I updated the answer. *Obscuring* is when a field or local variable hides a package or type, e.g. `String java=java.lang.String.valueOf(0);` does not work because here the variable name `java` *obscures* the package name `java`.